# COMException CreateInstance failed on publish

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently developing a C# WebAPI project that references a third-party api dll. The component is a simple COM reference that I added to the visual studio project.
The web API is published on an intranet server (IIS) with integrated security & user impersonation turned on, anonymous auth turned off.

When running the web api in visual studio (2015) on my local machine, everything works perfectly.

When running the published web api on our IIS server, everything also works fine, however when I send a request to a controller action that uses the third party library, I receive following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   Additional information:
>       CreateInstance failed.
>   at ThirdPartyLib.Connect()

The third party dependency was installed on the server (as well as my dev machine) using their installer. This registered a set of dll's and installed accompanying software. I have verified correct installation. In fact, a simple winforms application using the same dll works just fine.

Process Monitor shows w3wp.exe is using the correct dll.

I'm not sure what I'm missing?
If this is a rights problem, how would I go about solving it?

Comment: does the project has sufficient right to access the dll?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find out. UAC is turned off. It's an intranet server using integrated security so my account is being impersonated when I access it.

Comment: What does "is installed" mean? Is it registered? What does "I have a C# web API project" mean? Do you have the source code? How do you call the COM component? What have you tried? Did you run Process Monitor so see where it tries to load the DLL from?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I've edited the post with some extra clarifications.

Comment: May you need to add some permissions in DCOM in your IIS?

Comment: first try to set your api's security account to an admin account in IIS manager. If this solves the problem then it is the problem of permission. Then you would probably need to give the account that you are running under the permission to access that dll

Comment: Change Application pool user to a user with higher permissions for test. Also you can run that part of code with higher permission, for example take a look [at this](https://platinumdogs.me/2008/10/30/net-c-impersonation-with-network-credentials/).

Comment: @RezaAghaei This solved the problem. Just one more question: if user impersonation is turned on (and the user should have sufficient rights), why should the application pool user still need admin rights?

Comment: Can you confirm this is not related to 64 bit vs 32 bit? If your third party dll is 32 bit but IIS is running in 64 bit, then the com object may failed to initialize.

Comment: @Bikswan If you perform impersonation correctly it also works: `<identity impersonate="true" userName="r.aghaei" password="mypassword"/>`. I checked it for some permissions like filesystem permissions and it worked the same way which Application Pool Identity works. It precedes Application Pool Identity. But pay attention impersonation in webconfig or in code, just works if application pool user have sufficient rights to allow impersonation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change Application Pool Identity to a user with higher permissions.

**Note:** You can use ASP.NET Impersonation using web config to run the whole application with a specific identity or using code to run just a part of code using a specific identity. For example I tested `<identity impersonate="true" userName="r.aghaei" password="mypassword"/>` for a file system permission and it worked properly. Just pay attention impersonation in webconfig or in code, just works if application pool user have sufficient rights to allow impersonation. For more information about how to use impersonation inn config or code see [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306158) MSDN KB article.

Also don't neglect least privilege principal.